# Can we create a failover for a replication distribution database?

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, replication

I have an SQL VM on Azure. I need to replicate the database from that VM to another SQL VM on another cloud network (Transaction replication).

If I configure the distributor to be on a seperate SQL VM, I still have a chance that this machine will fail, skipping some transactions. I read that [distributor database can't be mirrored or used as part of an availability group](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/40f25fd4-d1a3-4be7-bef5-a23c1e4be7cb/failover-clustering-ofthe-distributor-and-subscribers-in-sql-server-2012-standard-edition?forum=sqldisasterrecovery), and Azure SQL VMs d[o not support AlwaysOn Failover Cluster Instances.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2721672/en-us)

How would I ensure that my distributor database will not go down and that my replication will always work?

Comment: i think you misread the support article you're linking to above. SQL Server AlwaysOn is actually supported in SQL Server Azure VMs, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870962.aspx

Comment: What I meant is that you can create an AlwaysOn group for specific databases, but you cannot create a failover for a complete SQL instance. AlwaysOn availibility groups do not support the distribution database, which is my problem :)